# problem with your selected data store on the ASP.NET website Administration tool

Tags: asp.net

Using the website administation tool, it always give error for database.

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
    <add name="FTESqlMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         connectionStringName="FTEDashBoard.ConnectionString" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
         applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
  </providers>          
</membership>

<roleManager>
  <providers>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
      <add name="FTESqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="FTEDashBoard.ConnectionString" 
           applicationName="/" 
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>          
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

It is giving me this error:

> There is a problem with your selected
>   data store. This can be caused by an
>   invalid server name or credentials, or
>   by insufficient permission. It can
>   also be caused by the role manager
>   feature not being enabled. Click the
>   button below to be redirected to a
>   page where you can choose a new data
>   store.
>
> The following message may help in
>   diagnosing the problem: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. and when i want to choose
>   datatsource is giving me The following
>   message may help in diagnosing the
>   problem: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object. at
>   ASP.providers_chooseprovidermanagement_aspx.Page_Load()
>   in
>   c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\Providers\chooseProviderManagement.aspx:line
>   13 at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.ArglessFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o) at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint

iam really not usre why in tool it is not able to acess database.. my connectionstring in web.config is

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="FTEDashBoard.ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=logsuatsql01;Initial Catalog=CMNBS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=FTEDashboard;Password=dashbrdFte!@#;Max Pool Size=500;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;Connect Timeout=600"/>       
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: when iam selecting it is giving Provider Management  
Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.

Comment: Does the database exist?  Do you have access to it?  Does the user context under which the site is running have access to it?

Comment: hi David .. yes database exist .. ans all aspnet_userrs table exists in different database so i changes my conenction string     <add name="Application.ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=logsuatsql01;Initial Catalog=ApplicationConfiguration;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=FTEDashboard;Password=dashbrdFte!@#;Max Pool Size=500;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;Connect Timeout=600"/>

Comment: What file is that at the top that has "rolemanager" in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the error you might want to enable roleManager like:

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
```

**Edit 1:**

Flaw in your connection string. Remove this: AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf; And you have your aspnet membership tables in your said DB - CMNBS right?

Comment: noo in application_configuration thatsw hy i changed connectstring.. and why AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf this has to be removed..

Comment: My bad...since you have you membership tables in application_configuration database, there is no need to use that AttachDBFile.... syntax. Make sure your membership and roles are using right connection string.

Comment: i added but still error persists  in connection string i added these 2  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="FTEDashBoard.ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=logsuatsql01;Initial Catalog=CMNBS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=FTEDashboard;Password=dashbrdFte!@#;Max Pool Size=500;Connect Timeout=600"/>

    <add name="Application.ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=logsuatsql01;Initial Catalog=ApplicationConfiguration;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=FTEDashboard;Password=dashbrdFte!@#;Max Pool Size=500;Connect Timeout=600"/>

  </connectionStrings>

Comment: <system.web>   <membership>        
        <providers>
          <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
          <add name="FTESqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
               connectionStringName="Application.ConnectionString"
               enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
               enablePasswordReset="true"
               requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
               applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
               passwordFormat="Hashed"

Comment: maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
               minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
               passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>        
     </membership>

Comment: for roles   <roleManager enabled="true">
        <providers>
          <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
          <add name="FTESqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="Application.ConnectionString"
               applicationName="/"
               type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
      </roleManager>

Comment: it si is giving  There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

Comment: when i got to chosse new datasource it gives An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ASP.providers_chooseprovidermanagement_aspx.Page_Load() in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\Providers\chooseProviderManagement.aspx:line

Comment: 13 at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.ArglessFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o) at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: How about this..drop SqlDataSource on a test page. Configure that SDS to connect to your Application.ConnectionString database. See if that is successful.

Comment: means... can be more elaborate

Comment: i tried soem different database its giving me database connection sucessful.. in security tab where u add users it is giving The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion', database 'ApplicationConfiguration', schema 'dbo' is this a permission error right?

Comment: Yes it is permission related...check there are some solutions here http://forums.asp.net/t/1002764.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem as well. I figured out that all I had to do was rebuild my solution.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

This issue is mostly generated when the solution is cleaned!
So try to Rebuild entire solution and that will solve the problem.